# How to get the IP address from a DNS for a host name?

Tags: delphi, dns, ip, delphi-xe3

I have this function that retrieves the IP address if I use `GetIP('server-name')` or `GetIP('google.com')` in my Delphi 2006.

But now that I am trying it on `Delphi-XE3` it's not working. Any ideas?

```
function GetIP(const HostName: string): string;
var
  WSAData: TWSAData;
  R: PHostEnt;
  A: TInAddr;
begin
  Result := IPNULL; // '0.0.0.0'
  WSAStartup($101, WSAData);
  R := Winsock.GetHostByName(PAnsiChar(HostName));
  if Assigned(R) then
  begin
    A := PInAddr(r^.h_Addr_List^)^;
    Result := string(WinSock.inet_ntoa(A));
  end;
end;
```

It seems that `R` is not being assigned because the result is always `'0.0.0.0'`

Comment: Have you checked the other parameters of `R`? Are they nulled?

Comment: Change your `HostName` parameter type to `AnsiString`.

Comment: @TLama it worked! How does that matters!?

Comment: It matters because `PAnsiChar` is a pointer to an `AnsiChar` which is a single byte in size, whilst your `HostName` parameter is of type `string` which is 2 bytes in size per char in your Delphi. You are pointing to a string of different size. Btw. a compiler told you about this with *W1044 Suspicious typecast of string to PAnsiChar* warning.

Comment: Optionally, you can let the `HostName` as it is, but before you pass it to the `GetHostByName` function through that `PAnsiChar` typecast, you can typecast it to `AnsiString`, something like the following `GetHostByName(PAnsiChar(AnsiString(HostName)))`.

Comment: @TLama you should make that an answer.

Comment: I was not receiving that advice because I putted {$WARNINGS OFF} in the file. :-(

Comment: Don't turn warnings off. :-) Warnings can be very important (as you see here). I always compile with hints and warnings on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The big difference between these two versions of Delphi is that the modern Delphi natively uses wide UTF-16 encoded strings, and the older version has ANSI encoded strings.

Many API functions have both wide and ANSI versions. But the functions you are calling in Winsock are steadfastly 8 bit only.

You can make your code work as before by explicitly using 8 bit text encoding.

```
function GetIP(const HostName: string): string; 
var 
  WSAData: TWSAData;
  R: PHostEnt; 
  A: TInAddr; 
begin 
  Result := IPNULL; // '0.0.0.0' 
  WSAStartup($101, WSAData); 
  R := Winsock.GetHostByName(PAnsiChar(AnsiString(HostName))); 
  if Assigned(R) then 
  begin 
    A := PInAddr(r^.h_Addr_List^)^; 
    Result := WinSock.inet_ntoa(A); 
  end; 
end;
```

---

Now, observant readers will say:

> What if the host name has non-ASCII characters? Isn't it a shame to be constrained by these rather feeble fixed length 8 bit encodings?

Well, the recommended function for translating host name to address nowadays is the Unicode function [GetAddrInfoW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738519.aspx).

Comment: For some reason @TLama did not write this up as an answer. Questions need answers. Without answers, the asker has nothing to accept. Hence my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a self contained example of what I use to resolve IP addresses on XE3-XE7, using winsocks2 and unicode support.

It is not performant as the socket support is initialized and deinitialized at every call, but the refactor is trivial.

Also, note that it is not optimized on purpose to allow easy maintenance.

```
uses
  Winapi.Winsock2;

type
  PAddrInfo = ^TAddrInfo;
  TAddrInfo = packed record
    ai_flags: integer;
    ai_family: integer;
    ai_socktype: integer;
    ai_protocol: integer;
    ai_addrlen: NativeInt;
    ai_canonname: PCHAR;
    ai_addr: PSOCKADDR;
    ai_next: PAddrInfo;
  end;

function GetAddrInfo(const nodeName: PCHAR; const serviceName : PChar; const hints: PAddrInfo; var result: PAddrInfo): integer; stdcall; external 'ws2_32.dll' name 'GetAddrInfoW';
procedure FreeAddrInfo(const addrInfo: PAddrInfo); stdcall; external 'ws2_32.dll' name 'FreeAddrInfoW';

function ResolveIpAddress(const hostName: string; const ipv6: boolean): string;
const
  BUFFER_SIZE = 32768;
var
  data: TWSAData;
  error: integer;
  requestError: integer;
  r: PAddrInfo;
  s: string;
  hints: TAddrInfo;
  buffer: TArray<byte>;
  length: DWORD;
begin
  error:= WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), data);
  try
    if (error = 0)  then
    begin
      r:= nil;
      try
        ZeroMemory(@hints, sizeof(TAddrInfo));
        if (ipv6) then
          hints.ai_family:= AF_INET6
        else
          hints.ai_family:= AF_INET;

        requestError:= GetAddrInfo(PCHAR(hostName), nil, @hints, r);
        if (requestError = 0) then
        begin
          length:= BUFFER_SIZE;
          SetLength(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
          if (WSAAddressToString(r.ai_addr^, r.ai_addrlen, nil, @buffer[0], length) = 0) then
          begin
            setLength(buffer, length * 2);
            s:= TUnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetString(@buffer[0]);
            exit(s);
          end
          else
            exit('0.0.0.0');
        end
        else
          exit('0.0.0.0');

      finally
        FreeAddrInfo(r);
      end;
    end
  finally
    if (error = 0) then
      WSACleanup();
  end;
end;
```